# Reset Password Using Html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, passwords

I Have a requirement where i have 3 input fields namely

> 1.old password
>    2.new password
>    3.confirm password.

For which i need to apply rules as follows.

> 1.Old and new passwords should not match.
>   2.No field should be empty.
>   3.New password and confirm password inputs should be same.

**If all these validations passes then only form should be submitted.**
Here is the Html file for which i need to apply js

```html
<form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h2 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Change Password</h2>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" name="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="livicon" data-n="pen" data-s="16" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0" ></i> Save</button>
                <button type="reset" name="Reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="livicon" data-n="trash" data-s="16" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0"></i> Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Old Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" value="" placeholder="Enter the Old Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>New Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" value="" placeholder="Enter the New Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" value="" placeholder="Re-enter the New Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>

</form>
```

thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything which is not working ? If **no** then you will need a contractor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace with your ids..

```
    function checkForm()
   {
    var oldP=document.getElementById("oldP").value;
    var newP=document.getElementById("newP").value;
    var confirmP =document.getElementById("confirmP").value;

    if(oldP!=""&&newP!=""&&confirmP!="")
    {
      if(oldP!=newP)
      {
        if(newP==confirmP)
         {
          return true;
         }
         else
          {
            alert("Confirm password is not same as you new password.");
            return false;
          }
      }
      else
     {
      alert(" This Is Your Old Password,Please Provide A New Password");
      return false;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     alert("All Fields Are Required");
     return false;
    }
}
```

An in thml you need to add

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm();" ----- >
```

For reset you can create a function somting like this

```
function resetForm()
{
        var oldP=document.getElementById("oldP").value="";
        var newP=document.getElementById("newP").value="";
        var confirmP =document.getElementById("confirmP").value="";
}
```

and call when you want form reset.

Comment: But if i use dialog box instead of alert..its not working..any reason for that

Comment: What is not working... form submitted without validation??

Comment: i have one dialog box instead of alert...if i apply that form will be submitted without validation

Comment: you are using jquery dialog or not... if possible post some code.. so i can get whats going on. i think problem is because of script asynchronous execution.

Comment: you can see  the jquery i am using in updated question

Comment: try this not tested but will work i think...` setTimeout('call you dialog',10)`

Answer (score 1):

create a function and call on onClick of button

```
<button type="button" name="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Function();"><i class="livicon" data-n="pen" data-s="16" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0" "></i> Save</button>
```

Your javascript Function  will be Like this

```
  <script>
    function Function() {
        var oldpasswprd = document.getElementById('oldPassword').value;
        var newpassword = document.getElementById('newPassword').value;
        var confirmpassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value;
        if (oldPassword == "" || newpassword == "" || confirmpassword == "") {
            alert('Please fill all the details');
        }
        else if (oldpasswprd == newpassword) {
            alert("Old password and New Password cannot be same");
        }
        else if (newpassword != confirmpassword) {
            alert("password mismatch");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly you should catch the click avtion on submit button and check the fields

```
$([name=Submit]).on('click', function(e) {

   if (($('#oldPassword').val() == "")||($('#newPassword').val() == "")||($('#confirmPassword').val() == "")) {//check 2
       e.preventDefault();
  }
  if ($('#oldPassword').val() == $('#newPassword').val()) {//check 1
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   if ($('#newPassword').val() != $('#confirmPassword').val()) {//check 3
       e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

P.S. i wrote code in this style because i want to show all steps. shurely you can combine 'if's in one to clear your code. as example u can combine check 1 and check 3 and put it in else block of check 2

Answer (score -2):

```html
<form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h2 class="page-header"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Change Password</h2>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="button" name="Submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="livicon" data-n="pen" data-s="16" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0" ></i> Save</button>
                <button type="reset" name="Reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="livicon" data-n="trash" data-s="16" data-c="#fff" data-hc="0"></i> Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Old Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" value="" placeholder="Enter the Old Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>New Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" value="" placeholder="Enter the New Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" value="" placeholder="Re-enter the New Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input group -->
            </div>

</form>
```